# Find the sum of induction

Tags: induction

I just started to learn induction, and I could not find a solution for this question:
Given the induction : $$1^2+2^2+3^2...+n^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$$
find the sum of : $$1^2+7^2+13^2+...+(6n-5)^2$$
Can anyone help please?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @MoranTailu Please show some effort when asking a question. You can add what you have tried, and also where you are stuck to improve your question.

Comment: Basically it boils down to expanding the bracket, to get an $n^2$ term, an $n$ term, and a constant term. Now you can use the formula for the sums of $n^2$ and $n$, and simplify.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(6k-5)^2=36\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2-60\sum_{k=1}^{n}n-25\sum_{k=1}^{n}1=36n(n+1)(2n+1)/6-60n(n+1)/2-25n$.

Answer (score 0):

$(6n-5)^2=36 n^2 - 60 n + 25$

sum is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(6k-5)^2=36\sum_{k=1}^n k^2-60\sum_{k=1}^n k+25\sum_{k=1}^n 1=$$

$$=36  \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-60 \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+25n=6n(n+1)(2n+1)-30n(n+1)+25n= $$

$=\color{red}{n (12 n^2 - 12 n + 1)}$

Hope this helps

Comment: Why the sum of k is k(k+1)/2?

Comment: @MoranTailu $$\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$1+2+3+\ldots+(n-2)+(n-1)+n$ sum the first and the last, the second and the last but one and so on. The sum is always $(n+1)$ and you have $n/2$ of these sums. So the result is $(n+1)n/2$